# Utilization of a service item

Tags: simulation, modeling, anylogic, utilization

I'm trying to create a Bar Chart that shows the Utilization of a "service" item in Anylogic. I've created a resource pool and linked it to the service beforehand.

The usual "propertyname.statsUtilization.mean()" doesn't work

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a bar chart to show utilization of a resourcePool... notice there that a service doesn't have an utilization, but the resources have.

So add data to the bar chart and use on value:

```
resourcePool.utilization()
```